# Failed automatic review test

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

While I was reviewing the close vote queue I've run into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605614/unknown-bug-in-simple-java-ship-game).
It was marked as `unclear what you are asking`.
I've read the question carefully together with the comments.

I've decided to <kbd>leave open</kbd> because the problem was solved in the comments.
Then I was told that this was a test and that I'm not paying attention`.

So my questions are:

- How can it be that question is not clear and in the same time it's solvable in a short discussion in comments?
- Shouldn't such test let you review questions/answers which are clearly good or bad and not lead you to such a mine field?

Honestly it breaks my motivation to do review tasks. I think that everybody has right to have his/her subjective opinion in such arguable cases.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, please comment on. I'm always open for a constructive critique.

Comment: I downvoted because I think that question is terrible. I get caught out by audits as much as the next guy, but if someone brings their audit to meta and I think it's a fair audit I'll be downvoting.

Comment: @OGHaza Thanks for clarifying. Terrible is not a good word here in my opinion. I would say it's far from ideal but still I don't find the question `unclear`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bad question that adds no value to SO. No one is going to find it in a search in the future and be helped by an answer to it. And the question text itself is unclear - basically just "it freezes" and a huge code dump with no effort by the OP to debug. The fact that someone was able to dig through the code and notice the problem doesn't mean that the question was actually clear.

Comment: To follow up, this is the reason why answers are not shown during a review. It doesn't matter what the answer are like, if the question is bad, the question is bad.

Comment: I don't see "core dump" in my post. The code dump in the question is not easy to read, it's 60+ lines of annoying horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Maybe it's also my case. I've spent to much time reading this question and finally it became clear to me what OP is asking.

Comment: Actually if you think a question is not useful, you can down-vote it. [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5498/76887)

Answer (score 9):

The fact that a question is answered in comments in no way means that the question is not "unclear".  It could mean any number of possibilities.  In this case it looks like someone took the time to parse through a particularly poor and unclear question and was able to muddle through it to figure out an answer.  (In other cases someone will simply guess at an answer.)  That doesn't mean that the question isn't unclear.  If that person, or someone else, takes the time to edit the question and clear it up it could *become* a clear question.  *If* such an edit takes place, the question could possibly be reopened.  But that *hasn't* happened yet, and the question is *still* unclear.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I should have at least edit the question to make text more readable. The fact that I understand the question doesn't mean that it's not unclear - I'll keep it in mind.